# How to get location name using mapkit in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am new in iphone development and right now i am facing problem for developing developing an application in which i need to get coordinate(lat, long) when user tapped on screen for two second and also get user location name,i got coordinate but i am unable to get user location name on which user tapped. so kindly help me on that?

Comment: How are you defining name? Address? Merchant?

Comment: i need current location name, like if'll tap on school just say and in response i'll get that specific school name, is this possible? and how can?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5+ use [`CLGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) and its [`reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation%3acompletionHandler%3a) method.

In your case, you're probably most interested in the `areasOfInterest` property.

Example:

```
CLGeocoder* gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
double lat, lon; // get these where you will
[gc reverseGeocodeLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    for ( CLPlacemark* place in placemarks ) {
        if ( place.region )
            NSLog( @"%@", place.region );
        // throroughfare is street name, subThoroughfare is street number
        if ( place.thoroughfare )
            NSLog( @"%@ %@", place.subThoroughfare, place.thoroughfare );
        for ( NSString* aoi in place.areasOfInterest )
            NSLog( @"%@", aoi );
    }
}];
```